# Run Minecraft Launcher through a Java Program in a different directory?

Tags: java, file, directory, minecraft, launcher

I am making a program in Java that involves me starting up the Minecraft launcher through the program itself. I've seen a way to do this using ProcessBuilders and stuff like that. However, I do not want the launcher to run to the default minecraft folder directory (minecraft on mac, .minecraft on windows). Is there a way that I can run the launcher through my program with the files set towards a different directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following command line you can make the new launcher use another directory:

`minecraftLauncher.exe --workDir path/to/your/other/minecraft`

The path can contain shortcuts, like `%appdata%` or `%homepath%`, etc.

Comment: How would I go about doing this on a Mac? EDIT - I got it! In terminal, you would use "open Minecraft.app --args --workDir path/to/folder/you/want"

Comment: nice find @Blockhead7360